# TwoWayBinding with Listview and XmlDataprovider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I searched a lot but I didn't find a solution for my problem.

I have an XML-File

```
<Module>
<Accounting>
    <tag tagname="tag1" displayname="display1">True</tag>
    <tag tagname="tag2" displayname="dispaly2">False</tag>
</Accounting>
</Module>
```

And that's my problem:
I want to bind this XML-File to a listview where I can see the displayname and a checkbox where I am able to (un)check the tag (two-way-binding)

my XAML-file:

```
<ListView Height="134.113" Width="227.409" Margin="0,-100,30,10">
                    <ListViewItem>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding XPath=./Module/Accounting/tag}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=./Module/Accounting/tag/@displayname}"/>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListViewItem>
                </ListView>
```

But the listview only displays the first Item "display1" but not the second one.. anyone an idea why?
(could there be any problem because I have (another) xmldataprovider?)

thanks
ps: sorry, english is not my first language ;)

Comment: Use the [ListView.ItemsSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) for binding a list.

Comment: If you are using a single column then I suggest to use `ListBox`. If you are planning to display multiple columns then refer proper setup of XAML `ListView`... http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1

Comment: I tried it some time ago, but if I set the ItemsSource-Property in the listview I get the Exception "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I see what your problem is...if you set the `Items` collection by defining an item in XAML (which is what you are doing)...then you aren't allowed to set an `ItemsSource` as well.

Take away the `ListViewItem`...and define how you want your items to appear by defining `.View` or `.ItemsTemplate` for your `ListView` so that it knows how to display your items.

See here:

- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-the-listview-part-1
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b47444b1-a566-4787-9364-a2fbff481354/

---

Use the `XmlDataProvider` as follows:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26875/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding

If you want to be able to create new nodes in the XML document then use this:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/144820/WPF-XmlDataProvider-Two-Way-Data-Binding-Enhanced

And bind to the items in your document:

- http://dotnet-experience.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/wpf-working-with-xml-and.html
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2006/09/19/762085.aspx

Comment: But I do have an xmldataprovider, which is set to another listview - so I can't use this xmldataprovider because I want to select other data?! should I create a second xmldataprovider?

Comment: Are you saying you have 2 listviews looking at the XML data at the same time?...and our they both using the XmlDataProvider in there ItemsSource?

Comment: I have 2 listviews looking at the XML data, but only 1 listview uses the XmlDataProvider (Because I want to see different Values in the listviews)

Comment: You were setting an item, so then it stopped you using ItemsSource....see answer above.

Comment: but if I set the ItemsSource-Property in the listview I get the Exception "Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource"?!

Comment: so now I set the itemssource to listview and made a gridview-column with the property DisplayMemberBinding and now it works - thanks